# IronPython.Runtime.UnboundNameException: 'name 'true' is not defined'

Tags: python, c#, visual-studio, ironpython

Hello I try to run my python code on Visual Studio with C#. But when I ran this code I got this error "IronPython.Runtime.UnboundNameException: 'name 'true' is not defined' " . I am new on these things ( IronPython and to run python code in C#) so sorry my poor presentation from now. That is the my c# code :

```
private static void Option2_IronPython()
        {
            var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
            var script = @"C:\users\Toshiba\SUPPLYDEMMAND.ipynb";
            var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(script);
            var argv = new List<string>();
            argv.Add("");
            engine.GetSysModule().SetVariable("argv", argv);
            var eIO = engine.Runtime.IO;
            var errors = new MemoryStream();
            eIO.SetErrorOutput(errors, Encoding.Default);
            var results = new MemoryStream();
            eIO.SetOutput(results, Encoding.Default);
            var scope = engine.CreateScope();
            source.Execute(scope);
            string str(byte[] x) => Encoding.Default.GetString(x);
            Console.WriteLine("Errors:");
            Console.WriteLine(str(errors.ToArray()));
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Results");
            Console.WriteLine(str(results.ToArray()));

        }
```

Here is the details of error :

```
Errors:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Toshiba\SUPPLYDEMMAND.ipynb", line 7, in <module>
    "scrolled": true
NameError: name 'true' is not defined
```

And here is the my python code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd 
import requests as req
import dateutil as pdate
import transparency
from transparency.electricty.markets import gop
import datetime 
import time

x = datetime.datetime.now() 
today = datetime.date.today() 
tomorrow = today + datetime.timedelta(days = 1)  
tomorrow = str(tomorrow)



supply_demmand = gop.supply_demmand_curve(date=tomorrow)

col_name="Price"
first_col = supply_demmand.pop(col_name)
supply_demmand.insert(0, col_name, first_col)

grouped = supply_demmand.groupby(supply_demmand.Hour)

df_list = ['df'+str(i) for i in range(0,24)]

df_list[0] = grouped.get_group(0)
df_list[0] = df_list[0].drop(columns=['Hour'])


for j in range (1,24): 
        df_list[j] = grouped.get_group(j)  
        df_list[j]= df_list[j].drop(columns=['Hour'])
        df_list[j]= df_list[j].reset_index(drop=True)
        df_list[0]= df_list[0].reset_index(drop=True )
        df_list[0]= pd.concat([df_list[0],df_list[j]], axis=1)
df_list[0]["Supply"]= df_list[0]["Supply"] * -1

path = "Supply_Demmand.xlsx"

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine = 'openpyxl')

df_list[0].to_excel(writer,sheet_name = tomorrow)
writer.save()
```

Actually I translated the part of these codes from Turkish to English so If you try to run on your ide you can get the error .I just wonder the logic of this error ,can you explain to me ? Thanks for all helps.

Comment: Not sure where the code is that sets the scrolled attribute but python has `True` and `False` for bool just as c# has `true` and `false`.

Comment: I think there isn't any value as true o false but I don't know. At least I didn't see the scrolled attribute in this library (line 7) ,how can i found this attribute ?